# Determine script length at beginning of Zip file

Tags: spring, bash, spring-boot, jar, zip

I got a spring boot app, with the bash loader in the beginning. When I unzip it, the script in the beginning gets lost. I need it though for re-assembly. So the idea was to split it off with `head -c`. But I have no idea how to determine the byte location efficiently. `less` tells me the amount of bytes of the script when I open the zip with it, but I'd like to automate it. Is there a possibility to determine it with `(un)zip`? Or is there another easy way?

I thought of determining the end location of `exit 0`. In my current app, this is at 8720. With

```
echo 'ibase=16;obase=A;'$(xxd nevisadmin-app.jar | grep -m 1 "exit 0" | awk -F: '{print $1}') | bc
```

I get 8704 (because it's at the end of the line), but this is super fragile, because it'll fail, if the `xxd` output is not in the same line e.g.

```
000021f0 ... bla bla ex
00002200 ... it 0 binarystartshere
```

Thanks

Comment: It would help to have more information. Could you manually extract one script and post it here? Hint: It is unlikely that the compressed data starts in the middle of the line. You probably can use `head -n` instead of `head -c`.

Comment: Solved it. `grep -a -n "exit 0" springboot-app.jar  | awk -F: '{print $1}'`

Comment: @user857990 Consider answering your own question with the solution, instead of writing it in a comment. That way it's easier to see for others that there is an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that search for `exit 0` is a reliable way to determine the end of the script of spring boot.

Extracting the script would be done like this":

```
head -n $(grep -a -n "exit 0" springboot-app.jar  | awk -F: '{print $1}') springboot-app.jar > startscript.sh
```

So it doesn't determine the length, but that becomes irrelevant to the original question. 
If someone looks up this question, the answer would be to instead of redirecting the output to a file, one could pie it to `wc -c`.